# Android crt0.o error while making flite/main folder in android flite

Tags: ubuntu, for-loop, android-ndk, flite

I am getting the following error when I'm trying to make in `flite/main` folder of android flite

> android-ndk-r4-crystax/build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.0/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: crt0.o: No such file: No such file or directory collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

How do i solve this?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading NDK? Newest version is r8. r4 is pretty old.

Comment: android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Hai thnks.
i tried with NDKr8 also.I got this while doing make in main folder

/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../build/arm-android/bin/flite] Error 1

Comment: Have you tried a standalone toolchain for NDK?